# del in Python functions deleting variable before the line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code:

```
foo=None
def bar():
    print(foo, flush=True) # UnboundLocalError
    print('MARK')
    del foo

print(foo)
bar()
#print(foo)
```

Basically I have a function that calls del in it. However, when I run the program, I get `UnboundLocalError` for that `'foo' referenced before assignment`. If I comment out the `del` line, the exception is gone. I suppose the del should be called exactly on the line it is on, so that the variable is invalidated only after that. But it doesn't seem to be the case.

Is this expected behavior? (Specifically, I'm using Python 3.6.2)

Comment: What are you even trying to do here?

Comment: @melpomene Trying to delete a global variable from inside a function.

Comment: Doesn't that need a `global foo` declaration in the function?

Comment: @melpomene, Yes you're right. But why does that triggers a error on the print line?

Comment: You either need a global foo or you need to define foo in your function

Comment: Presumably Python counts `del foo` as a modification of `foo`, so it implicitly creates `foo` as a local variable. Which you then try to print before it was set.

Comment: @melpomene Oh, that makes sense. Thanks.